# create array by conditions

Tags: javascript, random

I want to insert numbers to an array by the next following:

1. the number should be between 1-5
2. the first number can't be 1, the second can't be 2, etc..
3. chosen number can't be inserted to another index

for example:

[1,2,3,4,5]

I randomize the first number: 1 [condition 2 doesn't exists: 1 can't be in the first index, so I randomize again and got 4).

so new array:

```
0 - 4
1 - 
2 - 
3 - 
4 -
```

I randomize a number to the second cell and got 4, but 4 was inserted to the first element [condition 3], so I randomize again and got 2, but 2 can't be the second element [condition 2], so I randomize again and got 5.

```
0 - 4
1 - 5
2 - 
3 - 
4 -
```

etc

I tried to init a vec by the numbers (1-5):

```
var array = new Array();

array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 3;
array[3] = 4;
array[4] = 5;

var newarr = new Array();

function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var rand;
        // check condition 2
        while((rand = getRandomInt(1, 5)) == (i+1));   
        newarr[i] = rand;
        //array.splice(i, 1);
    }

    // print the new array
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        alert((i+1) + '->' + newarr[i]);   
    }
});
```

but I need to add condition 3 to my code,

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var rand;
        // check condition 2
        while((rand = getRandomInt(1, 5)) == (i+1) || $.inArray(rand, newarr)) // Also check, if generated number is already in the array
        newarr[i] = rand;
        //array.splice(i, 1);
    }

    // print the new array
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        alert((i+1) + '->' + newarr[i]);   
    }
});
```

But beware. If you generate for example this array:

```
[2, 1, 4, 3]
```

You will end up having an endless while loop, since the only available number is 5, but it can't be inserted in that position.

Answer (score 1):

```
var values = [1,2,3,4,5];
var output = [];


for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    do{
       var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length);
    }while(values[index] == i +1);
    output[i] = values[index];
    values.splice(index, 1);
}

console.log(output);
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/aJ8sH/